# What is a 'shift adder' in the context of combinational logic

Tags: logic

On my lecture slide there is one page mentions 'shift adder' which I struggle to understand.

The context is within digital logic, combinational logic, binary addition and multiplication. Then on one slide it has:

```
In this lecture we have looked at:
Decimal & Binary number systems
One's & Two's complement
.....
.....
Self study:
Floating point numbers.
Hexadecimal numbers.
Half adders & Full adders.
**Shift adders** (and how they can be used to do multiplication)
```

Searching 'shift adders' on google or youtube does not bring back many directly related answers. I wonder if I should search for something else?

Thanks

Comment: Probably [this](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/multiply.040.html) or [Booth's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) ?

Comment: not sure, though i was thinking of logic circuits, as are half adder and full adders?

Comment: I think the mention of multiplication is a big hint - shift and add is one way of doing binary multiplication.